# Assignment with function declaration

Tags: c++

I am trying to learn c++ and am following [this online book](http://www.cprogramming.com/c++book/jumping_into_c++_sample.pdf) and although mostly good, sometimes I feel things aren't explained that well.

On page 163, when talking about linked lists, he shows this code:

```
p_enemies = EnemySpaceShip* addNewEnemyToList( p_enemies );
```

It isn't completely filled in with context, but I believe p_enemies would be a declared pointer, and addNewenemyToList would be a defined function. What I am wondering is how the expression would work, and is this proper code. It doesn't make sense to me because it looks like a method declaration, having the return type right there, but it is there after an assignment. What is this?

Comment: The only way this could work is if `EnemySpaceShip` is an object, in which case it would be multiplied by the result of the function call. Are you sure there were no braces that casted the result of the function?

Comment: btw, the link to online book is currently a link to an attachment in your gmail, so we can't view it :P

Comment: @MikeTrusov, Seems to be this one: http://www.scribd.com/doc/105834938/Jumping-Into-c

Comment: Ok, looking a bit before that in the book, casting would be useless. I believe it's supposed to be: `p_enemies = addNewEnemyToList( p_enemies );`

Comment: Looks like an error in the book to me.  I think it should be `p_enemies = addNewEnemyToList( p_enemies );`

Comment: For what it's worth, we do have a [good book list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). I can't personally give an opinion on that one.

Comment: p46: Here’s a very basic example of a compiler error message:
`error: 'cout' was not declared in this scope`.
If you see a message like this, make sure that you both have your include statement for
iostream
and
`using namespace std;`
at the top of your program!_  Not yet convinced.

Comment: I would not recommend this book. Explaining pointer arithmetics before standard containers? Well, if it was called "Jumping into C with some C++ bolted on" I would understand that.

Comment: Please, please, please, for the life of your future coworkers, STOP READING THAT BOOK, forget what you've seen there and pick one from the already mentioned [Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list?lq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code snippet does not make sense.

This is the only way I could see this snippet as valid:

```
p_enemies = (EnemySpaceShip*) addNewEnemyToList(p_enemies);
```

Result:
If p_enemies is a pointer of the type EnemySpaceShip, this will assign the return value of the "addNewEnemyToList"-function to p_enemies after converting the returned value to a EnemySpaceShip pointer.
If not, the line will fail.